# Add one tap call icon ( another extra icon alongside main app ) on android app. How to do?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am developing an android app . Where I want to create two app icons, one for the main app ( where there will be much features ), and another one is for just doing specific job ( calling ). User must be able to open the other icon app just using google assistant.
To be more specific, one icon is for the main app ( named : " mario " ) and the other icon ( named " hook " ). So when user says " ok google, start hook " , the hook app must be launched and a call to be made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an activity for specific job, define it in your manifest file like in the code below and just add intent-filter. For two lunch icons, you should have two activities in your manifest with intent-filter action MAIN and category LAUNCHER.

**EDIT1:**
To set a specific name for a launcher, you need to add a label in  inside manifest. Google assistant should be able to find it by given name and open desired app activity.

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example...SpecificJobActivity"
        android:label="Specific Activity Launcher Name"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**EDIT2:**
To have both of your activities running as different apps simultaneously, we have to add *android:launchMode="singleInstance"* *android:taskAffinity="com.example.AffinityA* for all our entry points activities. It should look like this in your manifest file:

```
<manifest...>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example...Activity1"
        android:label="App launcher 1"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:taskAffinity="com.example...Activity1"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example...Activity2"
        android:label="App launcher 2"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:taskAffinity="com.example...Activity2"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</manifest>
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks . This works. But I found a bug in it. If I open the main app in background , the other app shows the same state. But when I remove the first one from background. The second one does it's job properly.
It happens for the second app also. Any solution for that ?

Comment: @ZulkerNayeen Okay, I updated my answer, lets try again.

Comment: @ZulkerNayeen Im glad I could help.